# Wp_login Action Hook Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function in my functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'the_function', 99 );
function the_function( $login ) {
    $user = get_user_by('login',$login);
    $user_ID = $user->ID;
    //do something with the User ID
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('first authentication ran successfully for " . $user->user_email. "!')</script>";
}
```

It's supposed to show a pop up box once the user logs in but nothing seems to happen at all. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Does the hook not trigger the  function immediately?

Comment: It's working for me, but don't do that because you will get some errors. Where did you put the code ?

Comment: At the very bottom of the functions.php file.

Comment: Weird ... and you try to log in by the wordpress "/wp-admin" page or custom log in page ?

Comment: I'm actually using Auth0 as the login system for our site. But I've also tried with "/wp-admin" but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try deactivate the plugin and log in with wp-admin to see if the alert is displaying. Anyway, I think you need to find the right hook for the login with your plugin. It may be not wp_login

Comment: Ahh good idea. I will try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164107/discussion-between-alex-vand-and-gabed123).

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue! did you all ever figure it out. i'm using the basel theme? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299443/wp-login-not-working-but-wp-enqueue-scripts-working